# I have cURL installed on Ubuntu 16 with PHP 7 but i get still Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, curl, php-7, ubuntu-16.04

I have done sudo apt-get install curl, sudo apt-get php5-curl, sudo apt-get php-curl but i get undefined function for curl_init()

does anyone know any solutions for this?

Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php 
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

Comment: try checking `php -i | grep curl` to see if it outputs anything or check if you see curl in `php -m`.

Comment: After i did php -i | grep curl, i get this. /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
curl

Comment: this error did not exist on php5

Comment: okay, how about php -m ? can you see curl in the output? nevertheless you should be able to get going all okay with just `sudo apt-get install php-curl`

Comment: It's also very likely the php7 package is called `php7.0-curl`

Comment: This is the result for php -m:
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

Comment: i have already the latest php7.0-curl. I'm still trying to research more on this because i believe i've installed already all necessary libs for cURL to work

Comment: Did you restart apache  (if you are using apache2) `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or `service apache2 restart` afterwards? It does seem like you have it installed just not enabled. :)

Answer (score 5):

Check what version of PHP is apache using ,By using `phpinfo();` function.

Checking is important because you might have switched to lower version for any reason (Like it was in my case).

Now from command line run this command to install curl

```
*(Don\'t copy this) sudo apt-get install php[version of php]-curl*
```

For example if it is **5.6** then use

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
```

After that, don't forget to restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I was facing same issue with installed php7 curl.. But when i checked I found that the enable php version was 5.6

So it is for some1 who might face same

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 16.04 running php7.0, you should specify the version like so:

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`

Then, as always, restart apache with

`sudo service apache2 reload`

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `phpenmod curl` and restart apache. Hope this help (;

Comment: i tried this and I got this result 'Module curl ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available.' , i guess it's getting curl in the wrong directory since i'm using PHP 7

Comment: try enabling php7 mod like @Ekn's comment and specify php version in `phpenmod` command like: `phpenmod -v 7.0 curl`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having a similar issue when installing a php extension and still getting `undefined`:

1. Run `php -i | grep EXT_NAME` to see the output if the regex matches anything that has `EXT_NAME` (in above case `curl`) in your `phpinfo()` or simply make a test file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and see if you spot the extension.
2. Run `php -m` to see loaded extensions and check if you have another installation that is taking precedence via `php -v` or more than one php.ini file using `find -name 'php.ini'` or `locate php.ini` in the root directory.
3. Don't forget to restart apache (or any other similar service) and/or enable if you have installed a module.

**3#** for apache can be done via running `service apache2 restart`

If you're building from source another possible cause might be that you forgot to recompile PHP with (again, in this case `curl`) `--with-curl[=DIR]` after installing an extension.

Comment: @AceJordan you might need to disable mod php5 and enable php7 via: `a2dismod php5` and then `a2enmod php7.0` then `service apache2 restart`

Comment: That of course requires you to install `libapache2-mod-php7.0` first.