# Curl installation Ubuntu PHP 7 failing - package not found

Tags: ubuntu, curl, php-7, apt-get, php-curl

Trying to install php-curl at ubuntu keeps failing.

I have PHP7 at:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 16.10

Release:        16.10

Codename:       yakkety

Tried running

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

And

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

PS:

Runned:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279594/1506788 to solve your issue

Comment: first off, this doesn't belong on stackoverflow.com , take it to superuser.com , second, next time you're having a problem, don't keep the errors a secret from the people trying to help you, that is just retarded.

Comment: but i bet your problem is that 16.10 became End Of Life at 20 july, 2017, and thus the update servers were shut down/re-purposed. i recommend updating to a supported version of ubuntu.

Comment: @hanshenrik your last comment is correct. But your first is partially retarded. The error is clear for those who had EVER used apt-get : package not found. Anyway thanks

Comment: @bhaskarbhatt It is written that i have tried exactly what that post says. php7.0-curl. And the problem is what hanshenrik said, EOL for 16 ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hanshenrik comment was correct. 
Ubuntu 16.10 is at End Of Life and apt-get update, upgrade won't work anymore which causes to some packages not being able to be installed.

Migrating to last version is what should be done